Debian Live CD password
I downloaded the latest live CD iso, debian-live-12.7.0-amd64-xfce.iso (MD5:4a3cf002e86c9f034578099670faaa47) and used dd to write it to a USB stick.
I booted the stick on a laptop and I got a graphical login screen.
I tried the following username/password choices:

user/live
debian/debian
live/live
Debian Live/live

but I cannot log in to the booted Debian Linux.
The documentation says it should just autologin, but it didn't do this for me.
How do I login?

Can't test this, so suggesting in a comment rather than an answer. 10.1 Customizing the live user confirms the default is user/live

What did you see when you booted it up? Was there a user name? Could you add a screenshot? Normally, with graphical login managers, you get a list of available user names, did you not see one?

I just downloaded the same ISO you did, verified the MD5sum (exactly the same as yours), and started it in a QEMU virtual machine. For me, it did autologin straight into a Xfce desktop.
I enabled a serial console (with systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0) which allowed me to try logging in via virsh console. That way I confirmed that the default user is indeed user with password live. Also sudo -i allows root access without asking for a password.
I also tried logging out of the GUI desktop and locking the GUI session; in both cases, the system accepted user/live as expected.
Assuming you actually verified the MD5sum of the ISO file after download and found it correct, the next probable source of problems might be a failing USB stick. Try writing the ISO to a different USB stick if possible.
